# Bedeutung von Damm

Tags: etymology

Das Wort „Damm“ wird im süddeutschen Raum für eine Erdaufschüttung verwendet, die z. B. bei Flüssen vor Hochwasser schützt.

In Norddeutschland wird das Wort jedoch auch für bestimmte Straßen (z. B. in Berlin) verwendet.

Was bedeutet im norddeutschen Kontext das Wort genau? Und woher kommt es? Hat es denselben Ursprung wie ein Damm am Fluss?

Comment: Beim Wort *Graben* verhält es sich ähnlich. In Wien ist der [Graben](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graben_(Wien)) zum Beispiel eine bekannte Straße.

Comment: Und der Hindenburgdamm führt zur Insel Sylt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Auch im Norddeutschen Raum ist ein *Damm* eine Erdaufschüttung; oft durch sumpfiges Gebiet. Auf diesen Dämmen verläuft dann die Straße. Die meisten der Sümpfe sind natürlich mittlerweile ausgetrocknet. (Interessant in dem Zusammenhang: Laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin#Gr.C3.BCndung_und_Mittelalter) geht der Name *Berlin* "vermutlich auf die slawische Silbe *berl (Sumpf)* zurück".)

Comment: Der Kurfürstendamm in Berlin war übrigens ursprünglich ein [Dammweg/Knüppeldamm](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kn%C3%BCppeldamm)